# Error parsing json result from the Azure CLI: launching Azure CLI: exec: "az": executable file not found in %PATH%

Tags: azure, terraform, command-line-interface

I get this error running a "terraform plan". I authenticated terraform to Azure via CLI. I have set up an account subscription. How can I solve this problem?

Error: building AzureRM Client: please ensure you have installed Azure CLI version 2.0.79 or newer. Error parsing JSON result from the Azure CLI: launching Azure CLI: exec: "az": executable file not found in %PATH%.

Answer (score -1):

The error says that az is not found. So for this type of error simple way out is logging-in into Azure like below:

```
az login
```

[image]

Then the error goes:

[image]

And then you can check your subscriptions once like below:

```
 az account list
```

And following login step i got resolved my problem.
And also check if you are using latest Azure Cli version.
And also try the below command:

```
az account get-access-token
```

[image]

**References taken from:**

- [Terraform apply results in Error populating Client ID from the Azure CLI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70731154/terraform-apply-results-in-error-populating-client-id-from-the-azure-cli)
- [azure cli $Path error running in terraform cloud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72681536/azure-cli-path-error-running-in-terraform-cloud)
- https://forum.gitlab.com/t/teraform-gitlab-image-no-azure-cli/60534

Comment: "az" is not found, so it cannot login by using it ^^

Answer (score -1):

Terraform cloud needs an Azure access since your plan is running on the cloud.

First, you need to create a service principal for azure

```
az ad sp create-for-rbac --role="Contributor" --scopes="/subscriptions/SUBSCRIPTION_ID"
```

See this tutorial: https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/tutorials/azure-get-started/azure-build

After service principal is created, you get this in response:

```
{
  "appId": "...", - client_id
  "displayName": "...",
  "password": "...", - client_secret
  "tenant": "..."  - tenant_id
}
```

Then you can provide azure access for terraform using **one of these methods**:

1. Add Workspace variables via terraform cloud GUI. They will be treated as environment variables.

```
ARM_CLIENT_ID="..."
ARM_CLIENT_SECRET="..."
ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID="..."
ARM_TENANT_ID="..."
```

2. Or include them into your .tf file.

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
    
  subscription_id = '...'
  client_id       = '...'
  client_secret   = '...'
  tenant_id       = '...'
}
```

Hovever it's not a good idea to sotre sensitive data in config.
That's why you may use method #3:

3. Declare variables in your .tf file and pass them via command line

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
    
  subscription_id = var.subscription-id
  client_id       = var.client-id
  client_secret   = var.secret
  tenant_id       = var.tenant-id
}
```

```
terraform apply -var client-id='...' -var tenant-id='...' -var...
```

See this answer for details:
https://discuss.hashicorp.com/t/using-the-azure-provider-with-terraform-cloud/18177/2