# az login using federated service principal credentials

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-cli, terraform-cloud

I want to deploy resources in Azure through a workspace in Terraform Cloud.

I am using Terraform Cloud's dynamic provider credentials feature for authenticating to Azure, as described in [this](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/cloud-docs/workspaces/dynamic-provider-credentials/azure-configuration) article.
It involves creating a service principal with federated credentials and hence no secrets.

Its working fine and I am able to deploy resources in Azure.

However, I have a `local-exec` resource that uses `az login`

```
az login --service-principal -u <client-id> -p <client-secret> --tenant <tenant>
```

Since I don't have a `client-secret`, how do I use `az login` ?

I came across [this](https://github.com/Azure/login) article, that shows to do this via GitHub Action, but I dont want to go the Actions route.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Did you check using **az login --identity**? @Jaimin_Joshi

Comment: Hi @VinayB , I tried that, but getting the same error:
`az login --identity -u <client id>`

Error:

`Error: building AzureRM Client: please ensure you have installed Azure CLI version 2.0.79 or newer. Error parsing json result from the Azure CLI: launching Azure CLI : exec: "az":executable file not found in $PATH`

Comment: It works sometimes if you downgrade the `Az CLI` version too. Can you downgrade it to less than `2.6.0` and check? @JaiminJoshi

Answer (score -1):

*Need to check below: -*

> Since I don't have a `client-secret`, how do I use `az login`?

***Approach-1:***

Firstly, to work with `az login` without using `CLIENT_SECRET` you can try using `CLIENT_ID` and Azure `TENANT_ID` for logging purpose. To use these values set them as [environment variables](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/guides/managed_service_identity#configuring-with-environment-variables) with the help of `export` command in `AzCLI`.

***Or***

Go to `Terraform Cloud` and you needed to set the environment variables `CLIENT_ID`, `TENANT_ID` by choosing the specific `workspace >> variables` as detailed in [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75020976/19785512) by @Monkey Supersonic.

`export TENANT_ID = "xxx"`

Now use the local-exec resource to log into Azure and it works as expected.

```
resource "null_resource" "azlogin"
 {
  local_exec { command = "az login --service-principal -u ${CLIENT_ID} --tenant ${TENANT_ID}" 
   } 
  }
```

***Approach-2:***

Using `az login --use-device-code`command is another way to use the `local-exec` resource in Terraform Cloud without a `clientsecret`.

```
resource "null_resource" "azlogin"
 {
  local_exec { command = "az login --use-device-code" 
   } 
  }
```

Once you execute the above command, it prompts you to open the web URL and enter the device code as shown. Then you will be able to log into the Azure successfully.

[image]

***Approach-3:***

Other approach is using [managed identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/authenticate-azure-cli#sign-in-with-a-managed-identity) login. You can use the managed identity to sign in. The `--identity` flag is used to sign in with the resource's identity.

`az login --identity --username CLIENT_ID`

> Error: building AzureRM Client: please ensure you have installed Azure CLI version 2.0.79 or newer. Error parsing json result from the Azure CLI: launching Azure CLI : exec: "az":executable file not found in $PATH:

Coming to the above error, it comes when the `Azure CLI` is not properly installed or not identified in the system path. Sometimes upgrading the `Azure CLI` using `az upgrade` resolves this error.

After upgrading it, restart the `Azure CLI`. If upgrading doesn't work, then remove the existing CLI configuration and reinstall it again.

Reference MS Doc [CLI installation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli).

*Note:* If still the issue persists, check to see if the location where `Azure CLI` is installed is in your system's `PATH` environment variable. Add it if not present.

Refer the [github](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/14778) doc for the relevant issue.

Comment: Thank you, Jahnvi, for the detailed solutions.
Trying approach 1, I am getting the same error. 
Approach 2 is not feasible as the run has to be dynamic and no scope of manual intervention to enter code. 
Approach 3: I don't have control over, as it runs on cloud VMs which our org has no control over.

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling Az CLI and re-install it? @JaiminJoshi

Comment: were you able to make it work with the above comment? @JaiminJoshi

Comment: It runs on cloud agents, so I don't control the software on those agents. Basically, there might be a new container spun up every time I run the pipeline.

Comment: Do you mean that is related to pipeline issue? @JaiminJoshi